# Python: Saving parameters and product one by one

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

Im writing a program that is getting product name, it parameters, and saving it to a text file for now. Page is http://www.euro.com.pl/pralki,strona-1.bhtml I wrote this:

```
`url = "http://www.euro.com.pl/pralki,strona-1.bhtml"
source_code = requests.get(url)
plain_text = source_code.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
for product in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'product-main'}):
    for prod in soup.find_all('h2', {'class': 'product-name'}):
        temp.extend(prod.stripped_strings)
        for param in soup.find_all('div', {'span': 'attribute-value'}):
            temp.extend(param.stripped_strings)`
```

But it gives me a text file with more than 200k lines! Can't figure out how can I fix it or write it from start.

Comment: What do you actually want ? What is your problem ?

Comment: I just want to save product name and its parameters to file from that webpage to a file.

Comment: Isn't it doing that ?

Comment: As I said, after putting result in text file it's giving me a more than 200.000 lines,  it is unacceptable because when you look at this site, there are only 30 products on page, each with 4-5 parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this:

```
>>> len(soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'product-main'}))
30
>>> len(soup.find_all('h2', {'class': 'product-name'}))
30
```

I conclude that there are 30 instances of `product` and 30 instances of `prod` so this line

```
temp.extend(prod.stripped_strings)
```

gets executed 900 times. From your description of the problem I think you are expecting it to be executed 30 times.

Comment: Ok, now I see what I did wrong, but still can't figure out how to do it properly.